# Google Chrome - Zoom without changing the viewport

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, zoom

Maybe I overlooked something or don't know how to word my question well enough, but I was not able to find anything online about this.

I would like zoom in Chrome, without changing the viewport or the website changing at all. So, if I zoom in on a website, I can zoom in on a detail without my responsive design moving it around and scaling it to "correct" sizing.

Is there a chrome extension for this, or a way to enable such a zoom function in Chrome?

Answer (score 2):

This extension is exactly what you are looking for: [Custom Page Zoom](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/custom-page-zoom/jodiabicmogcbbiocceenmeflipeelle?hl=en)

but sadly, it doesn't have shortcuts.

**PS**: Bear in mind that this extension requests data access to all websites you visit for some reason.

Comment: Access to all data of all websites you visit... hmmm...

Comment: Also, no way to scroll to parts of page outside of zoom window - so it's not really useful

Answer (score 2):

If you have a precision touchpad (most new laptops have these) or touch screen, you can pinch-out to zoom.

Answer (score 0):

**For macOS**
Take webpage. Press Command and "+" button to zoom.

**For Windows**
 Take webpage. Press and hold Ctrl button and scroll mouse wheel up.

**Edit**

1) Go to System Preferences->Accessibility 
2) Select Zoom and Enable "Use Keyboard shortcuts to zoom"
3) Note down the shortcuts.
4) By default <kbd>⌥</kbd>-<kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>=</kbd> for zoom in 
and <kbd>⌥</kbd>-<kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>-</kbd> for zoom out.

Comment: Sorry, that is not what I meant though. I know how to zoom, but I don't want the page to actually change. I want a "visual" zoom, where the page doesn't change. Because with the "normal" zoom, you the webpage changes with it, if programmed well, I want to zoom in where the website stays static.

Comment: Pls check my edit.

Comment: I do thank you, again, but I only have linux and windows

Answer (score 0):

I never found the solution but do this:

Take a screenshot and paste it into my favorite image viewing program and zoom there.

Comment: What question are you answering?

Answer (score 0):

User agents ( Chrome, Firefox, Chrome for Android, etc ) have the default behaviour of setting the body to 100% of the viewport, to be precise, visual viewport. Hence, when the window is resized, the viewport ( layout and visual ) changes, which causes it to always *fit* the content and causing other undesirable ( not always ) consequences like changing the layout in responsive designs.

If you are using a mobile-first approach, set body's `min-width` ( in your media query ) to an absolute value and use `min-device-width` or `max-device-width` to trigger your media queries.

This would trigger media queries, not when the browser window is resized, but only when the content is rendered on a device whose size is mentioned in your media query.

Eg:

```
body {
width : 90%;
}
```

And use media query like:

```
@media screen and (min-device-width: 960px) {

  body {
   width : 900px;
  }

// Other CSS Rules to apply when device width > 960px
}
```

This will cause your layout to be responsive on mobile devices, but not on desktop even if your browser window is resized or zoomed. Instead, it puts a horizontal scroll bar when content is zoomed or resized.

By using this approach, you can also skip using the `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" >` tag ( although it is not recommended )

Hope this helps!